# Resistance of a cylinder contacted by two smaller circular faces

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrostatics, electrical-resistance

Suppose we have a solid homogeneous cylinder with radius $a$, heigth $h$ and conductivity $\sigma$. The top and the bottom face is contacted with a smaller circular face with radius $b$.

How can I calculate the resistance?

I know the two boundary cases:

- if $a = b$, then $R = \rho \cdot \frac{h}{A}$ simply $\propto \frac{heigth}{Area}$
- if $b = 0$, then $R = \infty$ because of the singularity of both points.

I also know how to calculate the resistance of a truncated cone: Divide cone into slice and sum up the resistances $d R$ of all the slices along the heigth. Also works with any other $r(h)$ dependency.

But I do not know what happens, when the contact face is smaller than the face of the body.

I guess if $b \gg h$, we can approximate, that the electric field for $r > b$ is $0$. Like the approximation for a parallel plate capacitor. Then the material outside the cylinder with radius $b$ would be irrelevant and the resistance $R = \rho \cdot \frac{h}{b^2  \pi}$

Comment: I accidentally flagged this as homework-like before I noticed that you had specified that cylinder radius $a$ and conductive patch radius $b$ were not necessarily the same, so apologies.

Comment: For this case, can you just describe the system as having radius function $$r(z)=\begin{cases}
b+(a-b)z/d & 0\leq z\leq d\\
a & d\leq z\leq h-d\\
a-(a-b)(x-h+d)/d & h-d\leq z\leq h
\end{cases}$$
and then compute a symbolic expression for $R(d)$, and then compute $$R_0=\underset{d\rightarrow0}{\lim}R(d)\text{?}$$ It basically considers it to be a chopped cone glued to a cylinder glued to a chopped cone, and goes in the limit of the cone being very flat. I'm not sure if it's possible to get a closed form, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: I actually thought of that, but didn't metioned it (my shame). I found the statement "If the taper is small, one may assume that the current density is uniform across any cross section." (ref: [6.7.3 Resistance of a Cone](http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide06.pdf)). Since $d \to 0$ the taper is $\infty$, one cannot divide the two cones into slices, because the current density is not uniform anymore.